# Getting blank screen after deploying code on upgraded AEM 6.3

Tags: aem

We have just upgraded AEM 6.1 to 6.3. I deployed our code-base into the new environment and just after installing it, getting a blank screen while accessing http://myhost:4502/aem/start.html or any page. If I uninstall my package, I get the normal screen.

I am getting below error in the error.log file-

```
*ERROR* [10.44.48.183 [1500665039114] GET /content/regent.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter Unexpected error: 
org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Unable to setup processor: Unable to get component of class 'interface org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer' with type 'versioned-clientlibs'.
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.ProcessorManagerImpl.getProcessor(ProcessorManagerImpl.java:485)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getProcessor(RewriterResponse.java:172)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterResponse.getWriter(RewriterResponse.java:110)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:103)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.getWriter(OnDemandWriter.java:38)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.helper.OnDemandWriter.write(OnDemandWriter.java:68)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.newLine(PrintWriter.java:480)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:629)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.printError(WCMDebugFilter.java:230)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:220)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:159)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:278)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:322)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:211)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:104)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:516)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:346)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:607)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:156)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:71)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:114)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:436)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:154)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:180)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:221)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:219)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:128)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to get component of class 'interface org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer' with type 'versioned-clientlibs'.
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.PipelineImpl.getPipelineComponent(PipelineImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.PipelineImpl.init(PipelineImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.ProcessorManagerImpl.getProcessor(ProcessorManagerImpl.java:478)
    ... 134 common frames omitted
```

This is just a piece of errors that I am getting in error.log file.

Anyone has any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace is pointing towards an issue with ACS Commons' [Versioned Clientlibs Rewriter](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/versioned-clientlibs/index.html) not registering properly.

As the [ACS documentation](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/) states:

> For AEM 6.2 & 6.3 use 3.x.x

So make sure you have installed version 3.9.0 in your AEM 6.3 instance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your application is taking some reference from ACS package and ACS is not installed in new AEM 6.3 instance. Try to install ACS package.

Comment: I think too. You configured the link rewriter with versioned clientlibs. That's sounds like the ACS Adobe Commons. Nevertheless if your code base is older, there were a lot other rewriter around before ACS AEM Commons.

Comment: We have already installed ACS package, but still getting this error and the blank screen. Any other pointers?

Comment: Can you install latest version of ACS in AEM 6.3 instance and what behavior do you see if you uninstall ACS package from your 6.1 instance? Is there any other custom link rewriting is written?

Comment: Thanks Sumanta- I did install the latest ACS package and it resolved this error.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me,I took acs commons and acs tools, created a new install folder in crx-quickstart(aem) and uploaded both the bundles and started aem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).